# How does an airline respond to the loss of one of its aircraft in a hostile country?

Tags: commercial-aviation, accidents, airlines

I was wondering if the steps are the same as an accident on home ground where there is a go team and how they set up the area around the crash site, with a team contacting passegner relatives.

Comment: Hostile countries tend to be avoided and not overflown by airlines to prevent these situations from happening

Comment: @Afe This has happened before, MH17 is a perfect example. They set a restricted area over the war zone, it was proved to be inadequat,e but based on how many aircraft flew over that week you can't say that airlines avoid overflying those areas. They fly over any area that has hostilities if they are told that it is okay and a internal risk assessment says its okay.

Comment: @Bullfrog For hostile country I understand a country that is politically an enemy of the country of registration of the aircraft (i.e. at war). Malaysia was "neutral" in the conflict between Ukraine and Russia

Comment: The "country of occurrence" must protect the area and conduct an investigation. The airline is not involved directly, but "*the State of Registry, the State of the Operator, the State of Design and the State of Manufacture have the right to appoint an accredited representative to participate in the investigation.*". You may read all details in this [BEA summarization of texts relevant to accidents](https://www.bea.aero/fileadmin/uploads/media/recueil_textes_reglementaires_ANG_PUBLIC_2019_01_10.pdf).

Comment: In MH17 accident mentioned in comments, Ukraine was the "State of occurrence", [ICAO was associated to the investigation](https://www.icao.int/Newsroom/Pages/Ukraine-requests-ICAO-assistance-in-MH17-accident-investigation.aspx) officially and UK AAIB analyzed the recorders after they were released by rebels. As for contacting relatives, this is done by the operator which knows who was on-board (the list has to be provided to investigators within 2 hours), operators are prepared to such occurrence and have procedures. States with fatalities can also participate to the investigation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Situations like this have happend, most recently was MH17 which was shot down over the Ukraine, many airlines up until then were flying over Ukraine with a minimum altitude applied to flights transiting (FL320). And many flights also flew over that week:

- Aeroflot - 86 flights
- Singapore Airlines - 75 flights
- Ukraine International Airlines - 62 flights
- Lufthansa - 56 flights
- Malaysia Airlines -  48 flights

I am using how MH17 was handeled to answer this question. *However, it should be noted that no two situations are the same and the way they handled this situation may never be used again.*

The area of the accident still had hostilities and was not held by the Ukraine government, who would traditionally secure the scene and invesitigate. This was held by Donetsk People's Republic, considered by the Ukrainians and moajority of the world as rebels.

Access to the area had to be negotiated and even though the got assurances of access and safety this was given and revoked at various times based on the war. Other problems that occured was the issue of the [site being looted](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2014/07/flight-mh17-crash-site-has-been-heavily-looted/374707/). Beacuse it couldn't be secured by investigators there where personal belongings and potential evidence removed.

In the end the black boxes where handed in and examined to have been [not tampered](https://www.cnbc.com/2014/07/17/e-crash-images-from-the-ground.html) with. In the end it was an international team of investigators that examined the site as the Ukraine's investigators where not trusted by the Donetsk People's Republic.

The biggest part of this investigation was negotitiation with multiple parties. Some of who may have caused the crash. That becomes the dificult nature of investigations in a war zone.

What happens at home to the victims families doesn't change.

Comment: Thank you so much